# Update DBSet without saveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

I try to reach the following:

- Add a new entity to the DbContext's dataset.
- Do no execute SaveChanges yet, as in case of any error after insert, the new entry should not go to database
- However I need to search later if the newly entry is in the Customer collection

The following what I have now:

```
public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

_context.Customers.Add(customer);
// NO _context.SaveChanges();
// ...
var existsingUser = _context.Customers
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CodeCustomer == customer.CodeCustomer);
// existsingUser = null, and should be valid populated object
```

If I execute SaveChanges, the existsingUser is not null anymore, but the data is saved to database.

```
_context.Customers.Add(customer);
_context.SaveChanges();
// ...
var existsingUser = _context.Customers
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CodeCustomer == customer.CodeCustomer);
// existsingUser = has object
```

Is there any possible solution to 'Really' add the customer to the Customers collection, without saveChanges()?
If so, please let me know,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the [`Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.103).aspx) property. From the docs:

> This property returns an ObservableCollection that contains all Unchanged, Modified, and Added objects that are currently tracked by the context for the given DbSet.

For example:

```
var existsingUser = _context.Customers
    .Local
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CodeCustomer == customer.CodeCustomer);
```

Comment: Wonderfull, this is what I was looking for. Is there any other property where I can fetch from both local and already existing db set?

Comment: No, you need to query both. Remember one queries the database as well as the local store. You could write a wrapper function to do both at the same time quite easily though.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to add to collection without `SaveChanges()`. `_context.Customers.Add(customer)` means that you mark this object to add to the database. Under the cabin EF context works like a transaction. You can make plenty of operation but only `SaveChanges()` save to database.

`_context.Customers.FirstOrDefault` requests data from database.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Not true, you can use the `Local` property - see my answer.